# Calculate total number of distinct users across years, cumulatively

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have a data.frame like so:

```
user_df = read.table(text = "id industry year
1 Government 1999
2 Government 1999
3 Government 1999
4 Private 1999
5 NGO 1999
1 Government 2000
2 Government 2000
3 Government 2000
4 Government 2000
1 Government 2001
5 Government 2001
2 Private 2001
3 Private 2001
4 Private 2001", header = T)
```

For each user I have a unique `id`, `industry`, and `year`.

I'm trying to compute a cumulative count of the people who have *ever worked* Government, so the cumulative count should be a count of the total number of unique users for that year and all preceding years.

I know I can do an ordinary cumulative sum like so:

```
user_df %>% group_by(year, industry) %>% summarize(cum_sum = cumsum(n_distinct(id)))

   year industry   cum_sum
  <int> <chr>        <int>
1  1999 Government       3
2  1999 NGO              1
3  1999 Private          1
4  2000 Government       4
5  2001 Government       2
6  2001 Private          3
```

However, this isn't what I want since the sums in the year `2000` and `2001` will include people who have already been included in `1999`. I want each year to be a cumulative count of the total number of unique users that have ever worked in Government at a given year. I couldn't figure out the right way to do this in `dplyr`.

So the correct output should look like:

```
   year industry   cum_sum
  <int> <chr>        <int>
1  1999 Government       3
2  1999 NGO              1
3  1999 Private          1
4  2000 Government       4
5  2001 Government       5
6  2001 Private          3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option might be:

```
user_df %>%
 group_by(industry) %>%
 mutate(cum_sum = cumsum(!duplicated(id))) %>%
 group_by(year, industry) %>%
 summarise(cum_sum = max(cum_sum))

   year industry   cum_sum
  <int> <fct>        <int>
1  1999 Government       3
2  1999 NGO              1
3  1999 Private          1
4  2000 Government       4
5  2001 Government       5
6  2001 Private          3
```

Comment: Wow! This is so simple and clever. Kudos to you.

Answer (score 2):

**1) sqldf** This can be implemented through a complex self-join in sql.  This joins each row to the rows having the same industry and same year or before and then groups them by year and industry counting the distinct id's.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select a.year, a.industry, count(distinct b.id) cum_sum
  from user_df a
  left join user_df b on b.industry = a.industry and b.year <= a.year
  group by a.year, a.industry")
```

giving:

```
  year   industry cum_sum
1 1999 Government       3
2 1999        NGO       1
3 1999    Private       1
4 2000 Government       4
5 2001 Government       5
6 2001    Private       3
```

**2) base**A base only solution is formed by merging the data frame to itself on industry and then subset to the same or earlier year and aggregate over industry and year.  This is inefficient since unlike the SQL statement which filters as it joins this creates the entire join before filtering it down; however, if your data is not too large this may be sufficient.

```
m <- merge(user_df, user_df, by = "indstry")
s <- subset(m, year.y <= year.x)
ag <- aggregate(id.y ~ industry + year.x, s, function(x) length(unique(x)))
names(ag) <- sub("\\..*", "", names(ag))
ag
```

giving:

```
    industry year id
1 Government 1999  3
2        NGO 1999  1
3    Private 1999  1
4 Government 2000  4
5 Government 2001  5
6    Private 2001  3
```